# Ninth avataram of Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Is *Buddha* ninth Avataram of Vishnu?

But *Lord Venkateshvara (Balaji)* is also an avataram of Vishnu who came to earth in Kaliyuga(will be exists on earth to the end of Kaliyuga).

Then Venkateshvara can be considered as ninth Avataram of Vishnu. Because he is know avataram of Vishnu, but How Buddha became ninth?

Comment: Actually, I asked the same question before. but lord Venkateshwara avataram was out of my mind at that time. Here is the link. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/927/93. As the answers suggests, that there are many avatars but the top ten differ in each scripture.

Comment: IMO, I strongly think lord Venkateshwara should be the ninth avataram because Tirupathi is known as _Kaliyuga vaikuntham_. lets see.

Comment: Ye, but I am pointing to only ninth avataram.

Comment: I know your post is different. I just linked my post to explain you. Apart from my above comments, I think lord Venkateshwara is not ninth avataram because they did not born on Earth. lord Vishnu came on Earth by changing their name to Venkateshwara. So, can't say.. _confusion_

Comment: In that case, `Matsya`, `Koorma` and `Varaha` avatarams also not born on earth

Comment: correct.. confusion increased. :)

Comment: difficult to understand history :) all because its not scripted completely from beginning.

Comment: @Bharadwaj as per wiki *Matsya*,*Koorma* and *varah* are First , Second and Third avatar respectively

Comment: @TheDictator no confusion with other avatarams, but ninth,
how `Buddha` is ninth? not because of modern scripts, but is that really mentioned in some other ancient scripts?

Comment: @Bharadwaj as per Wiki Buddha is 9th avatar. And in that question that guy has copied the same [content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashavatara). And i think we should consider that as an official source.

Comment: @TheDictator Leave the content or source. OP is asking here why lord Venkateshwara is not considered as ninth avatar instead why Buddha is considered? and is it mentioned in some scriptures? I am sure Wikipedia is not a Hindu scripture :)

Comment: @TheDictator The same link says that its all assumptions of ninth avataram. So Buddha may not be ninth

Comment: "This question may already have an answer here:" how? there is no accepted answer. But this question is not only Buddha, but also `Venkateshvara`

Comment: @Mr_Green I agree that the content is not needed. But i have searched some of the tirupati Balaji related site and i am not able to find anything regarding ninth avatar of Vishnu.

Answer (score 1):

See, we can't speculate who is the ninth *avatar* and who is not. We can only check what the scriptures say about it. Already there have been two-three questions regarding this on the site. So I am answering it briefly.

Scriptures describe incarnations of Vishnu as infinite. And not all incarnations happen in our material plane. Those incarnations in which the Lord descends to this material plane of existence are known as *avatars*. And even among those, only ten are prominent and most important as per the scriptures. *Mastya*, *Kurma*, *Varaha* all are *avatars* because the Lord assumed a seemingly material form for the sake of the earth and gods.

Now it's true that the ninth *avatar* is somewhat controversial because it portrays Buddha as an *avatar* of Vishnu. Why? Because Vishnu is a Vedic god and Buddha spread a non-Vedic tenet telling everyone to reject the Vedas and *yajnas*. Some say due to Buddha's influence as a teacher who affected so may people around the world, He was accepted as an avatar of Vishnu. We can't say whether it's true or not, but in the scriptures Buddha has been mentioned as an *avatar* of Vishnu. We can't change that. Otherwise Gaudiya Vaishnavas who accept Chaitanya Mahaprabhu as an incarnation of Krishna would certainly list Him in the ten *avataras*. So also many other sects and cults would replace the ninth *avatar* with their worshiped deity or preceptor. But then, they would not be able to provide scriptural proofs to back up their claims. It's because most of the scriptures mention Buddha as the ninth *avatar* and some also mention Balarama as the ninth *avatar*. **If we don't go by the book, then it's all just a matter of personal preference whom we accept as the ninth *avatar***, after all, all *avatars* are nothing but Vishnu Himself.

For scriptural references regarding the ten *avatars*, please see [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/944).

Comment: I answer this question with reference to Srimad Bhagavatam. Srimad Bhagavad Mahapurana has been composed by our Vyasa – the Twenty Eighth in Vaivasatha Manvantara – Maharishi Krishna Dwaipayana about slightly more than 5000 years ago.  It was written at the beginning of the present Kali Yuga which started 36 years after the end of the Mahabharata War.  This Purana covers the story of all the eight Incarnations of Lord Mahavishnu till then, Matsya (Fish), Kurma (Tortoise), Varaha (Boar), Narasimha (Half Man – Half Lion), Vaamana (Dwarf), Rama (Parashurama), Sri Ramachandra and Sri Krishna.

Comment: Unfortunately for us, Srimad Bhagavad Mahapurana is silent on the Ninth and Tenth Incarnation still to come. A passing reference of a few lines is available in verse 22: Chapter 4: XI Canto of Srimad Bhagavad Mahapurana thus: भूमेर्भरावत्रणाय यदुव्षजन्मा 
 जातः करिष्यति सुरैरपी दुष्कराणि |
वादैर्विमोहयति यज्ञकृतोsतदर्हान् 
 शूद्रान् कलौ क्षितिभुजो न्यहनिष्यदन्ते || 
Though being unborn and immortal, to reduce the burden of unrighteousness on earth the Lord will incarnate in the Yadu Dynasty and wrought such wondrous deeds that even the powerful demi-Gods cannot  perform. [continued]

Comment: Later He will incarnate again twice, firstly  to remove the blind faith in ritual animal sacrifice, the Lord will try to save the dumb beasts by His words, logic and and at the end of Kali Yuga He will incarnate as Kalki to rid the earth of the mlechas ruling it.                                                                      The reference to यज्ञकृतोsतदर्हान् विमोहयति स वादैरपि enunciates that He will by His speech disenchant the populace of the thirst for animal sacrifices in various Yagyas (Fire Worship by offerings). Does this refer to Lord Buddha? If so He can be treated as the 9th