# Stature of humans throughout the four Yugas

Tags: bhagavata-purana, yuga, avatars

In the Puranas, there are at least two stories that describe the difference between the human stature in Treta Yuga and Dwapara Yuga - the story of [Muchukunda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muchukunda) and [Revati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revati) and Kakudmi . In these stories the central characters from Treta Yuga observe that in the Dwapara yuga humans have decrease in stature and their metal and spiritual process are markedly declined. But, contrary to these stories in the Vamana Avatar of Vishnu, which is said to reflect the evolution of life from animals to various stages of human development, the human form is that of a midget. Is there a contradiction between these stories?

Comment: I think the resolution is simply that the comparison of the Dasavtaram to evolution is mistaken.  As I discuss in [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/927/36), Vishnu has had countless incarnations, not just 10; people just make different lists of what they consider as the "top 10".  And once you consider other incarnations of Vishnu, like Dattatreya and Kapila and Hayagriva and so on, you no longer get an ordering remotely similar to evolution.  Note that I'm not saying hat Hinduism is inconsistent with evolutions, just that the order of Vishnu's incarnations is unrelated to it.

Comment: And in any case, Vamana wasn't a human at all, he was a god.  He was one of the Adityas, the 12 sons of Kashyapa and Aditi, a group that includes Indra and Surya.  Parashurama, Rama, Krishna, Kapila, etc. are human incarnations of Vishnu, but Vamana was a divine incarnation of Vishnu.

Comment: Good question!! I'm not sure if there can be an exact answer for this one other than people's opinions only