# Why is Buddha a part of Dashavatar list?

Tags: vishnu

Simple and straight question: Doesn't buddha belong to another religion, that is Buddhism?

I found various lists all over the internet, and based on answers here, I want to know on what basis Buddha is included?
[What are the exact ten avatars of Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/927/what-are-the-exact-ten-avatars-of-vishnu)

Comment: Buddha was a Hindu sadhu and reformer of the vedic religion. His followers made it separate. Even today, however, if a dispute in Buddhism cannot be answered in the Pali texts, they will sometimes refer to the vedas. Also, most mandirs that only allow Hindus to enter, will allow Buddhists.

Comment: Source of this info? Buddha didn't believe in vedas or vedic principles

Comment: The reason Buddha is considered an Avatar is because of multiple reasons. One is his name is explicitly mentioned in some puranas as an incarnation of Lord Vishnu. Some people believe this to be an interpolation, but in any case, the name is there. Another reason is because the Buddha's teachings, his story and His philosophy is very much similar to Hinduism, particularly Vedanta. The third reason is because He is revered very highly by the modern Vedantins such as Swami Vivekananda, Sri Ramakrishna, Ramana Maharishi, Sri Swami Sivananda, etc. All the best!

Comment: @MohitC source Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda

Comment: I was researched heavily on this topic and would like to post an answer myself but it has been marked duplicate

Comment: @MohitC You can always answer the original question. THere is no compulsion that you must answer this question only. Please do so as I am interested to read your findings :)

Comment: @Sai I am not able to post on that too, It gives no option to add an answer

Comment: The Buddha in the dasavatara list is not Siddhartha Gautama of Sakya dynasty but a sanyasa avatara of Vishnu who aided Siva in the annihilation of tripura asuras.