# Is Lord Venkateswara an "avatara purush"?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Is Lord Venkateswara an avatar of Lord Vishnu? If so, what is its number (first, second, etc.)?

Also, in total, how many avatars of Lord Vishnu are there?

I read somewhere that there would be only two avatars of Lord Vishnu in Kaliyuga and they are Lord Buddha and Lord Kalki? Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: Lord Venkateswara is not Avatar. He is Vishnu himself. Concept of Dashavatar is moot topic.

Comment: See [What are the exact ten avatars of Vishnu?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/927/3500)

Comment: You are asking many questions under one title and some of them have been already answered (please use search before asking new questions). You need to make your question specific to Lord Venkateshwara.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! As mentioned by @sv. you are asking many questions under one title. You can search for questions using specific tags such as [tag:venkateshwara]