# Is Krishna the only avatar among dashavatara who had more than one wife?

Tags: krishna, avatars

Is it true that Krishna is the only avatar who was married to more than one woman?

Comment: Yes, why did you ask?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu in order to research whether it depends on the relativeness of dharma by time.

Comment: In Ramayana, multiple wives is not adharmic in itself. But Rama chose to have only one wife.

Answer (score 13):

Kalki Avatara in [Dasavatara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11209/3500) also has multiple wives (two wives), Padmavati and Ramaa, as per Kalki Purana. [Kalki Purana](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByTCDrDij9HBWVA4VHYzY2g4elU/edit?pref=2&pli=1) mentions how Lord Kalki married his two wives. (translated by Bhumipati Das)

**Chapter 10** mentions the marriage of Padmavati and Kalki.

> 14. After greeting Lord Kalki, the king worshiped Him with great respect and then brought Him to his palace, which had decorated pillars, gates, and residential quarters He then gave his daughter's hand in charity to the Lord
> 15. Thus King Brhadratha had his daughter, Padmavati, whose eyes were like lotus petals, who had the fragrance of a lotus, and who was born at a place where many lotuses grew, married to the Lord, who possesses a lotus like navel

**Chapter 24** mentions marriage of Ramaa and Kalki.

> 25. Thereafter, King Sasidhvaja summoned his sons from the battlefield and, as desired by his wife, handed over his daughter, Rama, to Lord Kalki in marriage.

**Chapter 33** of Kalki Purana describes Kalki pastime with His consorts:

> 5. Thus, the village of Sambhala, which was profusely decorated with blooming flowers, pious trees, forests, and gardens, became a holy place that granted liberation from material existence.
> 6. The master of the universe, Lord Kalki, who was especially pleasing to the eyes and minds of women, happily resided with PadmavatI and Rama in the village of Sambhala.
> 7. to 8. The Lord would mount His celestial chariot, which had been given to Him by Indra, and periodically visit holy rivers, mountains, groves, and islands. In this way, He would enjoy pleasure pastimes with PadmavatI and Rama. He thus appeared to be a most perfect, passionate male, afflicted by transcendental lust. Indeed, the Lord of Ramaa became so absorbed in thought of His consorts that He completely forgot whether it was day or night.

Comment: The Kalki avatar has yet to arrive so technically only Krishna had more wives.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Yes. But seems like OP wants to know in general among all Dashavataras.

Comment: I disagree he clearly said "was married". But I will upvote your answer since it adds value.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu See question before editing. I think Op wants to know in general.

Comment: We are told Kalki will appear at the end of kaliyuga.But kings are no more there.How will king Bhadranatha emerge in thisnsituation?

Comment: I clearly read OPs question. It is written in the past tense. Therefore my answer is correct.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu See question before edit, not after edit. I will edit question.

Comment: @Partha King can be any ruler of kingdom (country) (PM or President) assuming democracy exists till end of Kaliyuga.

Answer (score 1):

The Destroyer has already pointed out that the Kalki Avataar will have two wives.

**And so Kalki is THE ONLY AVATAR in the Dasa-avatars Who would have two wives.**

This is because, Sri Krishna is **NOT** counted in the Dasa-Avatars. The Dasa-Avatars are -Matya, Kurma, Varaha, Nrisimha,Vamana, Parasurama, Rama, Balarama, Buddha and Kalki.(Reference : Dasavatar-stotra by Jaydev).

Krishna is 'Bhagavan Svayam'. He is Avatari and Avatars are His amsas: "**ete chamshakalaah pumsah krishnastu bhagavan svayam"**.(**Srimad-Bhagavatam 1/3/28)**

So Jaydeva writes: 'Keshava drita Dasavidha rupa, Jaya Jagadisha Hare'.

Including Sri Krishna in the Ten Avatars is a misconception **as the most authentic list of Dasavatar comes from Jayadev.**

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Thanks so much,But I think Jayadev is a higher authority in this regard as he wrote the Dasavatar-stotra

Comment: Krishna is avatari, but he takes role of avatar (meaning he also descends to earth) also according to gaudiya vaishnavas. Scriptures do count Krishna as avatar. So he can be counted among avatars as well. But since people will think avatar means only vishnu amsa, Jayadeva seems to have included Balaram instead just to make Krishna's position more explicit.

Comment: Generally speaking Krishna is counted among the dashavatars. It is ridiculous to count Balarama as he did not change the history as powerful as the other avatars.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu actually Balaram is also counted as 20th avatar in bhagavatam 1.3.23. I know another scripture also counting Balaram but can't recollect. So it is not wrong to count him as avatar. Jayadeva is not gaudiya vaishnava. He is 12th century poet where as gaudiya-vaishnavism is of 16th century. But I agree when scriptures count only dasavatars, they count Krishna instead of Balaram.

Comment: "He is Avatari and Avatars are His amsas". Nowhere in the scriptures is this written so this is false.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu This is what is mentioned clearly in Srimad-Bhagavatam and the direct disciples of Mahaprabhu preached it.ete tamsakalaa pumsah krishnastu bhagavan svayam

Comment: @Partha As many people I do not consider Mahaprabhu an authority. That being said please show me the reference in the sb in which this is stated. The word amsa is as far as I know never used in any authoritive scripture.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu its there in bhagavatam.u can get it simply by searching net.To me Mahaprabhu is God and sorry i am not nnterested to communicate with anyone who does not accept Him as authority.

Comment: @Partha there is no such reference. 
Moreover, Mahaprabhu is widely NOT accepted as an authority.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu I have provided the sloka no of Bhagavatam in my answer. And its great to know that some people are there who can question Mahaprabhu.I bow down to you

Comment: @Wikash_hindu in multiple places in scriptures, the word amsa is used, you can ask a question if you want about the references for amsa in scriptures, I am sure it will be closed as too broad.

Comment: Not in authoritive scriptures that I have encountered.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu that shows that your encounter with authoritative scriptures is too limited..

Comment: Or that of you is too limited or are given false information

Comment: @Wikash_hindu don't act smart. I said if you don't know, ask a question.. In Gita also the word amsa occurs. .And tag me else i don't know if you commented.

Comment: @VivekAditya BTW in which scripture Krishna appears as one of dasavatara?

Comment: @Partha in many places, wherever 10 avatars are counted.. Krishna is counted.. Even Bhagavata purana counts Krishna as 20th avatar.. (A correction in one of my above comment. Balaram is counted as 19th)Then at the end just to distinguish him from other avataras "ete camsa kalah..." is spoken.

Comment: @VivekAditya i mean where in the scriptures are only ten avataras mentioned?

Comment: There are unlimited of course. Some puranas like Agni, Padma etc.. count 10. Garuda purana follows bhagavata purana style and counts 22 and says there are unlimited avatars. Even in Garuda purana, Balaram is counted as an avatar.