# Is Veda Vyasa still alive? If yes, where is he? How can one recognize him?

Tags: vyasa, siddhi, life-span

Some people say that Veda Vyasa is still alive with his body in the Himalayas. When I searched, I found [this link](http://mukundagoswami.org/is-vyas-still-living,734/). It is stated [here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/12/6) also.

**But where can we find him and how can we recognize him?**

It is also said that with the perfection of the mystic yoga, one can live as long as he wants (one of the siddhis). By the way who is Maru [here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/12/6)?

Comment: Not sure about the factual details, but about "where can we find him and how can we recognize him". With realized masters this is the general view: you cannot get to them, unless they want you. Even if you somehow found Sage's location, they would make themselves invisible or they would make sure you never are able to come there! But if they decide to show their Self to you, then it doesn't matter where you are! They can visit you in your Room! If one really wants to have darshan of Lord Vyasa then one needs to pray sincerely from Heart and Lord Vyasa will show Himself one way or another Sir..

Comment: Yes, Vyasa is alive.  Like most immortal sages (other than Agastya), he is currently somewhere in the Himalayas.

Comment: Maru is described as the descendant of Kusa, son of Lord Ramacandra. It is in the same chapter of Bhagavatam that you cited: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/12

Comment: He is still alive. Judging by the accounts of those that have seen him, He is pleased by anyone who has read and mastered his works - vedas or puranas or brahma sutras. If he chooses to reveal himself to you, you will recognize him.

Comment: I do not know how much true is this statement "Having achieved perfection in the power of mystic yoga". Since VedaVyasa is incarnation of supreme power NarayaNa, there is no need for him to achieve perfections in any yogas. He is there always, everywhere at all instance of time. Yes, VedaVyasa is still there in Badari Ashrama preaching the great souls. Don't go in search of Vedavyasa in Himalayas physically. You start deep diving into the scriptures (Mahabharatha, Bhagavata and other 17 MahapurANas) given by him and start growing up internally, he will only come to you

Comment: Find where mahendra parvat is u wil find him i gess

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan where is Agastya muni?

Comment: Unfortunately the links don't work. Please update the links so they work. Thanks

Comment: There are 7 Chiranjivees are still alive no suspect. If person awaken the sahastrar then he will be able to see any hidden thing .

Comment: @moonstar2001, "judging by the accounts of those that have seen him" - do u personally know someone who claimed to have seen him ?

Comment: @javatechnical, "Madhwacharya was the most recent one who meet Vyasa (1238-1317). So approximately 700 years have passed when someone met Vedavyasa and it was in Badri itself as the Sumadhwavijaya i.e. the biography of Madhwacharya states" So I believe still he Alive (because Immortal) and Vyasa like sages they don't want to hind in a place so may be he is roaming Himalayas and Banks of Ganga (since it's coming from Manasasarovar). How can we recognize someone (last seen 700+ years and No photo identity) we don't know how they are looks like? it's insane.

Comment: @ram I don't know them personally but have heard historical as well as autobographical accounts that I have no reason to disbelieve. For e.g., Tikkana who is one of the authors of Andhra mahAbhAratam had vyAza darzanam.

Comment: How is Vyasa still alive? If he is alive, then Bhishma should also be alive?

Comment: His mother satyavati denied bhishma of his rights. Bhishma should have been immortal and that satyavati's son knew future but why he did not prevent war? why is that vyasa made immortal. how is vyasa and kripacharya immortal? we know why parashurama, bali, hanuman, ashwathama, markandeya is immortal but why is vyasa and why is kripa immortal? kripacharya was part of 18th day night raid. In my opinion, Bhishma is immortal. Bhishma is the BEST.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, certainly Shree Ved-Vyasa is still alive. He being Chiranjeevi (immortal) is still alive.

The answer is clearly given about him in **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana - Skandha 8 - Chapter 13 - Shloka 15-16.**

It's said in those shlokas that Ved-Vyasa is still alive and living in their respective ashramas by Yog-Bala or Yogic Power.

> गालवो दीप्तिमान्रामो द्रोणपुत्रः कृपस्तथा ।
>  ऋष्यशृङ्गः पितास्माकं
>   **भगवान्बादरायणः** ॥15॥
>  इमे सप्तर्षयस्तत्र भविष्यन्ति स्वयोगतः ।
>  इदानीमासते राजन् **स्वे स्व आश्रममण्डले** ॥16॥
>
> gālavo dīptimān rāmo
>  droṇa-putraḥ kṛpas tathā
>   ṛṣyaśṛńgaḥ pitāsmākaḿ
>   **bhagavān bādarāyaṇaḥ**
>  ime saptarṣayas tatra
>  bhaviṣyanti sva-yogataḥ
>  idānīm āsate rājan
>   **sve sva āśrama-maṇḍale**
>
> O King, during the eighth manvantara, the great personalities Galava,
>   Diptiman, Parasurama, Asvatthama, Kripacarya, Rishyasringa and our
>   father, Vyasadeva, the incarnation of Narayana, will be the seven
>   sages. **For the present, they are all residing in their respective
>   asramas.[SB 8.13.15-16](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/13/15-16)**

I don't that think he is visible to us  directly because it's said that these people are living in their ashramas with their yogic powers. I think we need some divine Power (Teja) to locate and to see him. But I believe that if we wish he can appear before us if we call him with  pure devotion. Since he is an Avatara of Lord Vishnu. Good Luck.

Comment: "For the present, they are all residing in their respective asramas." - where exactly is this ashram? Somewhere close to his birthplace? "I think we need some divine Power (Teja) to locate and to see him." - do you have any sources to back up this claim? And why is that they've suddenly taken this non-physical form when they were all roaming freely in physical form visible to lay people during Ramayana and Mahabharata times?

Comment: "He being Chiranjeevi (immortal) is still alive" - Can you also add some sources from Hindu scripture that say Vyasa is a chiranjeevi?

Comment: @sv. - haha , I agree apart from Chiranjivi stotram there is no source for Ved Vyada's immortality , but if we look at another shloka from Vishnu Sahasara Nama i.e. "Vyasaya Vishnu Roopaya, Vyasa Roopaya Vishnave, Nmo Vai Brahma Vidaya, Vasishtaya Namo Namha" that does not only make him immortal,  but eternal as Vishnu himself also.

Comment: @sv. - I think their Ashramas i.e. their abods are not in this plane. Even though their physical abodes are here on earth. They are living in cosmic Planes (Ashramas) in subtle forms and can return to their physical state whenever required. And yes again it's just what i think , without scriptural evidence but the outcome of what i learned/seen so far from scriptures.

Comment: BTW come to chat when free. Not seen u in many days.

Answer (score 2):

Veda Vyasa is alive.

Not a lot of people know that Parashara did penance to have a son who will have great ascetic merit and Shiva blessed him that his son will be immortal.

> "Parasara said,--'**In former times I gratified Sarva, O king. I then cherished the desire of obtaining a son that would be possessed of great ascetic merit, endued with superior energy, and addressed to high Yoga, that would earn world-wide fame, arrange the Vedas, and become the home of prosperity, that would be devoted to the Vedas and the Brahmanas and be distinguished for compassion.** Even such a son was desired by me from Maheswara. Knowing that this was the wish of my heart, that foremost of Deities said unto me.--Through the fruition of that object of thine which thou wishest to obtain from me, thou shalt have a son of the name of Krishna. **In that creation which shall be known after the name of Savarni-Manu, that son of thine shall be reckoned among the seven Rishis. He shall arrange the Vedas, and be the propagator of Kuru's race. He shall, besides, be the author of the ancient histories and do good to the universe.** Endued with severe penances, he shall, again, be the dear friend of Sakra. **Freed from diseases of every kind, that son of thine, O Parasara, shall besides, be immortal.**

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a018.htm

So yes, Veda Vyasa is alive.

Comment: Technically it does not say he did penance for the son, he could have done other penances or other stuff that eventually ended with him meeting Maheswara and making the request.

Answer (score -1):

Yes..they have many divine knowledges, Sciences and arts to manifest themselves either visible or invisible; either be on earth or beyond.  They are beyond the limits of time, matters and nature, therefore we call them devas or god's while western people call them alians or extraterrestrials.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE! You should cite sources.